# how do you make a python aws lambda handler make an async call that takes a long time but have the lambda immediately return a requestId as a response

Tags: aws-lambda, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I'm trying to do this using the asyncio library but I don't really understand how it works. Shouldn't it just be as simple as calling the async function in the handler without an await in front of it? e.g.

```
def my_handler(event, context):

   someAsyncFunction() 
   return random_request_id
```

Please note that I don't want to wait for `someAsyncFunction` to return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Lambda doesn't work the way you are trying to use it. As soon as you call `return` in the handler of the Lambda function, the entire function runtime will be stopped by AWS. It isn't possible to return a response from a Lambda invocation while that same Lambda invocation is still performing any sort of processing task in the background.

What you can do is create two Lambda functions:

Function 1:

- Takes a `random_request_id` as input, and does some longer running processing and exits.

Function 2:

- Creates a random_request_id, calls Function 1 with [invocation type Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html) so it doesn't wait on that Lambda function to complete, and returns the `random_request_id`.

You could also consider placing an SQS queue between the two Lambda functions to decouple them.

---

This kind of multiple Lambda function workflow can quickly become unwieldy, so I recommend looking into [AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html) to orchestrate this workflow.

Comment: Thanks lol I realized it wasn't possible to return and then do processing with a lambda function a few hours after posting my question. I appreciate the detailed alternative solution!